# Oracle No Data Found for several Select Into statements

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I'm using several contiguous SELECT INTO statements in a PL/SQL procedure.  If any one of these Select statements results in NO DATA FOUND, I'd like to handle the error in a consistent way.  Is there a way to use one EXCEPTION routine within the same procedure for several Select statements?  I'd like to know which particular Select failed so that I can give the proper message.

```
Declare
  l_smtp_hostname varchar2(1024);
  l_smtp_port varchar2(1024);
  l_music_db_site varchar2(1024);
Begin
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_hostname from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_hostname';
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_port from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_port';
    Select lu_value into l_music_db_site from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'music_db_site';
End;
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I don't have access to the table creation commands. But I think it would be smart to prefer a dynamic use of the column type instead of working with varchar2. (Even if its memory usage is optimized and will only occupy the space actually used). 
The information about %TYPE is in the [PL/SQL User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#sthref163).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap each select in it's own block and call a common exception handler, or do something like this where you set a location variable as you progress through the code, and if an exception occurs, log the value of the location so you know where it failed like this:

```
Declare
  l_smtp_hostname varchar2(1024);
  l_smtp_port     varchar2(1024);
  l_music_db_site varchar2(1024);
  v_location      varchar2(50);
  err_nbr         NUMBER;         -- Holds a SQL error number if an exception occurs.
  err_msg         VARCHAR2(1000); -- Holds a SQL error message if an exception occurs.
  err_string      VARCHAR2(2000);
Begin
    v_location := 'location_1';
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_hostname from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_hostname';
    v_location := 'location_2';
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_port from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_port';
    v_location := 'location_3';
    Select lu_value into l_music_db_site from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'music_db_site';
Exception
  When NO_DATA_FOUND then
    err_nbr    := SQLCODE;
    err_msg    := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
    err_string := 'ERROR: ' || err_nbr || ' occurred: ' || err_msg;

    UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => 'program_name@your_company.com', 
                  recipients => 'support_team@your_company.com', 
                  subject    => 'ERROR in <program_name>', 
                  message    => 'Select failed at: ' || v_location || CHR(10)||CHR(10)||err_string);                                  

  RAISE; -- re-raise the error so the program fails.
End;
```

Comment: Hi Gary.  I tried this.  It worked fine.  This is more what I had in mind for this particular need.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Realistically, probably not.

You can have a single exception handler but then you won't know which step failed.  You could potentially get the line number of the error from the error stack and then parse the data from `dba_source` (assuming you really have a stored procedure not an anonymous PL/SQL block) to find the statement.  But that's a crud-load of work.

```
Declare
  l_smtp_hostname varchar2(1024);
  l_smtp_port varchar2(1024);
  l_music_db_site varchar2(1024);
Begin
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_hostname from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_hostname';
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_port from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_port';
    Select lu_value into l_music_db_site from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'music_db_site';
Exception
  When no_data_found
  Then
    <<do something>>
End;
```

You could add a variable that tracks where you are in the process.  That works but can lead to some ugly code

```
Declare
  l_smtp_hostname varchar2(1024);
  l_smtp_port varchar2(1024);
  l_music_db_site varchar2(1024);

  l_tracker varchar2(30);
Begin
    l_tracker := 'smtp_hostname';
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_hostname from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = l_tracker;

    l_tracker := 'smtp_port';
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_port from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = l_tracker;

    l_tracker := 'music_db_site';
    Select lu_value into l_music_db_site from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = l_tracker;
Exception
  When no_data_found
  Then
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Error at ' || l_tracker );
    <<do something>>
End;
```

Most often, you'd want to handle each exception separately.  Often by calling a procedure that logs your errors.

```
Declare
  l_smtp_hostname varchar2(1024);
  l_smtp_port varchar2(1024);
  l_music_db_site varchar2(1024);
Begin
  begin
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_hostname from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_hostname';
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      log_error( 'smtp_hostname', <<other parameters>> );
  end;

  begin
    Select lu_value into l_smtp_port from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'smtp_port';
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      log_error( 'smtp_port', <<other parameters>> );
  end;

  begin
    Select lu_value into l_music_db_site from mail_lookup 
          Where lu_type = 'music_db_site';
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      log_error( 'music_db_site', <<other parameters>> );
  end;
End;
```

Of course, you could take that code and factor it out into a function that takes a `lu_type` and returns a `lu_value` rather than duplicating the code in your block.

```
Declare
  l_smtp_hostname varchar2(1024);
  l_smtp_port varchar2(1024);
  l_music_db_site varchar2(1024);

  function get_lu_value( p_lu_type in mail_lookup.lu_type%type )
    return mail_lookup.lu_value%type
  is
    l_val mail_lookup.lu_value%type;
  begin
    select lu_value
      into l_val
      from mail_lookup
     where lu_type = p_lu_type;

    return l_val;
  exception
    when no_data_found
    then
      <<do something>>
  end;
Begin
  l_smtp_hostname := get_lu_value( 'smtp_hostname' ); 
  l_smtp_port := get_lu_value( 'smtp_port' ); 
  l_music_db_site := get_lu_value( 'music_db_site' ); 
End;
```

Comment: Hi Justin.  Thanks for the help.  I tried it.  The last example, the one with the function, worked fine.